# One Of the Category Url redirected to home page in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, log

I checked in Catalog Url Managment https://www.websiteName.com/wall-hanging.html

i checked **wall-hanging.html**  in target path and in Request Path also but there is no entry for this .

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the admin setting "Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management", **not include the '/'**, search `wall-hanging.html` or `wall-hanging` in the target path and Request Path.
2. Check the admin setting "Catalog -> Manage Categories -> (the category)General -> URL Key"
3. Check the `.htaccess` file in your site root directory.

Comment: I searched correctly but nothing found.

Comment: I can't visit your url. Is there one or more product in the wall-hanging category? Some settings will lead no product category redirect to homepage.